# Firefox plugin to copy text with its formatting Intelligently?

Tags: html, firefox, plugins

When viewing a webpage, I would like to copy a selection of text with its html formatting in one piece.
Meaning if some text is in bold and blue, I want the tool to create a style or class in the html which makes the text blue. Everything is contained in the produced html.

I have downloaded a similar plugin but the classes definitions are still external which means I have to get them separately. A non technical user would be at a loss here. I want the user to be able to copy and paste to a new webpage and that page just just works properly because the html copied contains everything.

This doesn't have to be a FF plugin. It could be IE or a Windows app.

Comment: Which part of the task of writing this plug-in are you having trouble with?

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe you could start describing a good benefit of using this sort of tool, someone might write one soon.

Comment: I am not a plugin developer. I am looking for such a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be able to accomplish this by using the Firebug for Firefox extension. I often use it to export the content of a web page for use rebuilding a similar object. Is this still too technical? Firebug is a powerful, viable option that it is worth learning, I think.

Comment: Since there is no firebug anymore how does that work with the Firefox Developer tools?

Answer (score 0):

I think the copy operation does this already. If I copy this page and paste it in a WYSIWYG editor such as TinyMCE (included in Wordpress), I get the formatting. For example the text of this page is (as pasted):

```
<h2><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365603/firefox-plugin-to-copy-text-with-its-formatting-intelligently">Firefox plugin to copy text with its formatting Intelligently?</a></h2>
```

The HTML markup is copied, but not external CSS. I suspect creating a piece of CSS that would apply to your standalone snippet of code the style it had within the DOM hierarchy would be horribly difficult if at all possible.

Comment: The plugin I mentioned copies as html but it doesn't copy the css information. 

A plugin like Firebug displays the css when you inspect any element. What I am asking is for the tool to grab that css and put it as an inline css. I don't see how that would be too difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Try [SnappySnippet](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/snappysnippet), it's a Chrome extension that allows to copy html and all the related css style of an element. It integrates itself into the Chrome console. I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you're looking for:

**Web Design Pirate:**
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-CA/firefox/addon/web-design-pirate-for-devtools/

It creates a new "Pirate" tab in the developer tools that lets you grab the elements you want, including all associated CSS.